# ASUS X453M Freeze on Splash Screen on Booting or Restart / Shutdown

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity, shutdown, reboot

just fresh install on new notebook ASUS X453M

it's often to hang on boot or restart ubuntu,

its only respond to force shutdown button

i must forceshutdown and boot many times to can login to dekstop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change OS Selection to Windows 7 rather than 8.1
in BIOS

no matter u dual boot with 8.1

its work for me now

Comment: Now you might like to [get two finger scrolling to work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/644411/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-no-synaptics-driver-loaded/644421#644421). I have the same machine. Good luck with the fan lol!

Answer (score 0):

To can figure out what's happening (if it is a hardware of software issue), reboot and choose from `grub` menu the `memtest` entry, and see if your ram is healthy.

If yes, boot in recovery mode, and see if the freezing occurs. 
If not, check the log file  called `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/dmesg.0`. 
If you have possibility, save it somewhere and share it with us.

If the recovery mode also freezes, boot from a live media, and check what's happening.
If that one is freezing also, you have a hardware failure (HDD or even mainboard can be faulty).