# Focaltech touchpad. Couldn't find synaptics properties.

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, focaltech

I have a problem with my touchpad; I can't scroll down with 2 fingers and I don't know why. I have searched on Google about my problem and I've found some answers but none of them don't work for me. 
One solution I found was to go in `System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad` and check the Two-finger scrolling, but I don't have that option.

[image: Touchpad Settings]

Another solution was to try to reinstall, which also didn't work. Yet another solution was to go in Ubuntu Software Center, type `synaptic` and install the Synaptic Package Manager but that didn't work, either.

[image: Installing Synaptic through the Software Center]

[image: Output of "xinput; dmesg | grep pnp"]

What can I do to be able to scroll with two fingers?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command. Also please specify you laptop model.

Comment: My laptop are Asus F550J

Comment: Please add output of the command. There may be two types of touchpads in this model with different drivers required.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3G7nYcs.png

Comment: I wrote the answer for you. The next time do not make screenshots. You can copy text from terminal and paste it here. You can do it now. Otherwise it can't be seen well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a Focaltech touchpad. The driver can be installed by running in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
```

You can run

```
 sudo modprobe -r psmouse
 sudo modprobe psmouse
```

to get it work immediately, or just reboot.

If you have 14.04, then you will have to reboot, because new kernel will be installed.

**UPDATE:** These touchpads are now supported by the 4.2+ kernels.
The kernel can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

The Focaltech driver from the PPA should be removed.

**I removed the PPA, because many people try to install the Focaltech driver for other touchpads!**

I have no Idea why they think they have a Focaltech touchpad.

**This is not a generic answer for all touchpad problems!!!**

Comment: Thx man, it rly works :D

Comment: `synclient` sometimes fails to load for me on Debian 8.2. The `modprobe` thing lets me recover it without rebooting, but how can I stop this from happening at all? The sporadic nature of this implies it might be some sort of timing conflict, but I don't really know how to start diagnosing it further.

Comment: @Pilot6, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms 
returns the following error:
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~hanipouspilot/ubuntu/focaltech-dkms'.
The user named '~hanipouspilot' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/focaltech-dkms'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'bluetooth':  Test bluetooth modules
 * 'file-roller':  file-roller
 * 'ideapad-laptop':  ideapad-laptop
 * 'rtlwifi':  Realtek wireless

Comment: I removed that PPA since it is not needed any more. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 it's Ubuntu 16.10
running sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial gives
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-xenial

Comment: You do not need to install anything for Focaltech to 16.10. Please ask your own question if you have some problems. Most likely you do not have a Focaltech touchpad. I removed the PPA because many people try to install it for non-Focaltech touchpads.

Comment: This is how to [ask].

Comment: @Pilot6 I know how to ask. Thought this is related. Anyway, have posted my issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/881289/i-am-not-able-to-find-many-of-the-options-in-my-mouse-settings

Comment: What if- $ xinput; dmesg | grep pnp
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                       id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]