# Ubuntu 14.04, touchpad scrolling does not work after kernal update

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, synaptics

Ubuntu 14.04, touchpad scrolling does not work.
 I was following along with this solution ([Focaltech touchpad. Couldn't find synaptics properties.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644411/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-no-synaptics-driver-loaded))

Laptop: Samsung NP535U3C-A01US

```
    :~$ xinput; dmesg | grep pnp
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ WebCam SC-13HDL12131N                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    [    0.358382] pnp: PnP ACPI init
    [    0.359371] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
    [    0.359673] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD0b00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active)
    [    0.359799] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 PNP030b (active)
    [    0.361333] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
```

So my touchpad isn't even recognized. I'm not sure what to do from here. Please help if you can. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You touchpad looks like this one:

> pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD0b00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active)

The "ELAN PS/2 Port Smart-Pad".

And now it's detected as a **PS/2 Generic Mouse**, therefore the scrolling feature is gone.

If it works before upgrade, this issue might be a regression bug, I will suggest you to open a bug report on [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) by following the guidelines in this [Debugging Touchpad Detection wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection).

Address the touchpad model name, PNP device ID in the report. Also it's crucial to mention that the scrolling feature works before upgrade. But not with the current kernel version (run `uname -a` in a terminal). You can boot to the previous kernel to verify this by [entering the grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) on boot, and select "Previous Linux version" there.