# Touchpad finger scrolling not working after Upgrade to 16.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch, synaptics

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Carbon Thinkpad.
The touchpad is not working properly. I can't scroll down with fingers.I face the same problem reported in
[Focaltech touchpad. Couldn't find synaptics properties.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644411/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-no-)

Image: [Scrolling properties not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKjAr.jpg)

Here is the output of the command xinput; dmesg | grep pnp
Image: [Command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWvhT.jpg)

Can someone please help in enabling touchpad scrolling?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: I tried installing/reinstalling this package. It did not help

Comment: apart from installing synaptics , also uninstall libinput :
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput