# I am not able to find many of the options in my mouse settings in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 16.10, synaptics

The options that are missing are tap to click, natural scrolling, etc.
[image]

Is it possible to figure out what is wrong?

Also,

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

gives

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Edit: Added xinput output

```
~ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command. 16.10 does not use synaptics by default.

Comment: Does multitouch like scrolling work?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes. But only scrolling.  Multi touch to right-click, etc. does not. Also, scrolling is the default and not natural scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.10 uses `libinput` instead of `xorg-synaptics` by default.

Ubuntu GUI does not support `libinput` options yet. Nor does `libinput` support `synclient` commands.

You can either configure `libinput` using the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-libinput.conf`, or uninstall `libinput` by

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

In this case `xorg-synapics` will be used, and you will have the GUI options back.

Make sure `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed. It contains `xorg-synaptics` software. It should be installed by default though.

For `libinput` configuration options see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man4/libinput.4.html

Comment: does it require a reboot to start appearing?

Comment: I think restarting the X will be sufficient, but you can reboot.

Comment: I did not tell to install anything. Yes, it is `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. It should be already installed.

Comment: There is nothing to change. `xorg-synaptics` is not a package name, but the name of the software.

Comment: @Pilot6 This has solved the issue. Thanks!